# Sprite Kit Texture Atlas: Define Image Format (RGBA4444, RGB565, …)

Tags: xcode, image, sprite-kit

How do I define the image format of a Texture Atlas in Sprite Kit?

For example, I want to set RGBA4444 or RGB565 as the output format to reduce memory usage. (Like in [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker).)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project build settings you can find Output Texture Atlas Format.

Step by step:

1. In the Editor area, select your project and click Build Settings.
2. Type Sprite in the search field, and press Return.
3. Just set it to desired format:

[image: Build settings for texture atlas format]

Comment: Is there a way to set dithering as well? (Like in TexturePacker.) See this post: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/

Comment: This seems to be outdated, unfortunately. Do you have any advice about how to achieve this in a *current* version of Xcode?