# How to change texture format in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In cocos2d it's possible to change texture format using

```
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
```

Is there any way to change texture format in Sprite Kit? I would like to generate sprite sheets using RGBA4444, but I can't find a way to set texture format in Sprite Kit.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Texture Atlas, you can change the "Output Texture Atlas Format" in the Build Settings. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21626731/867635

Or use a program like [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to create and export your sprite sheets in the desired format.

But I don't think it's possible do that directly from code. At least the public Spite Kit API doesn't offer that kind of method / property.

Comment: Thank you I'm aware of it. So there is no option to do it from code? Let's wait might somebody has answer how do it similar in Cosos2d,and if there is no way, I will accept this answer.