# How do I convert a PNG with alpha to RGBA4444 for using it in SpriteKit SKTexture?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

I have a stack of transparent PNGs that I'd like to use in a `SKSpriteNode` animation with `SKTexture`s. I'd need to adjust the memory usage of `SKTexture`s by reducing texture quality down from `RGBA8888` to `RGBA4444`.

How would I initialize `SKTexture` with `RGBA4444` texture format?

**Edit:** *IOS Swift Game Development Cookbook: Simple Solutions for Game Development* suggests that `SKTexture` would support PVRTC files as follows:

[image]

However, I couldn't get a `SKSpriteNode` to display a texture generated this way.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106245/how-to-change-texture-format-to-rgba4444-for-sprite-atlas-created-in-assets-xass/39928198#39928198

Answer (score 2):

I just tried and in Xcode 8 the option **Output Texture Atlas** described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625654/sprite-kit-texture-atlas-define-image-format-rgba4444-rgb565) is no longer available into **Build Settings**.

I suspect (but I could be wrong) the control has been now moved inside **Compression** as you can see in the following image.

[image]

Comment: I guess the only option to have `SKTexture` compress the texture data *in memory* is to use texture atlases? I didn't find any `SKTexture` initializer options that would point out to texture compression.

Comment: @MarkusRautopuro: Yes probably. However you should use a Sprite Atlas also for a faster CPU-GPU communication.

Comment: The problem is that I have large PNG files and a lot of them. The only option would be to create the sprite atlas programmatically. However, I didn't find a way to set the compression to `SKTextureAtlas`.

Answer (score 1):

I circumvented this by using [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to generate a texture atlas (.atlasc) file. With TexturePacker you can set adjust the compression and then access the texture atlas in your project as follows:

```
let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Atlas") // Atlas.atlasc in your project
let texture = atlas.textureNamed("original_texture_001.png")
```

Comment: As MoDJ pointed out in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39928198/2155985, that all textures in Sprite Kit will be loaded into memory as RGBA8888. I need to confirm this also.